# Element.offsetTop is unexpectedly incrementing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Even though I have found the answer, I'm creating this question for others to find if they have my same problem.

I'm creating a webpage as a tool for me to use in another project; the goal is for it to allow me to manipulate text overlaying an image and display the text's information such as its top and left attributes.

I ran into an issue when implementing [W3's method](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) for making elements draggable. When dragging an element, it's left value would change as expected, but the top value would increase by 16 for each call to `elementDrag(e)`, specifically each use of `elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";`. I tried many things and thought I was going crazy until I found the simple solution [on this page](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/position-absolute-top-0-bottom-0-not-working/310088). **The cause of the issue was that the element being dragged had a margin of 16px**, so `elmnt.offsetTop` would always be 16px more than `elmnt.style.top`.

[Here's the page in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0235cLu/1/) if you want to see my issue for yourself. It's still a WIP, and I'm a novice, so it isn't very polished.

1. Enter some text in the input field to the left of "Input here"
2. Press enter or click the "Submit" button
3. Click on the text that is placed over the missing image
4. Then click and drag as you normally would expect.
5. If you want to replicate the issue, delete `margin: 0px;` from the CSS for ".overlayText".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <p> element being dragged had a margin of 16px by default, so `elmnt.offsetTop` would always be 16px more than `elmnt.style.top`. This is fixed by adding `margin: 0px;` to the CSS for the class `.overlayText`.